# Boto3 Credential Issues In Fargate

Tags: boto3, aws-fargate

I have a Fargate task where the container is not getting proper credentials via boto3 (Python).  I have another AWS account where this works perfectly but having issues on this other account now.

Basically, boto3 has no issues generating signed URLs via S3 but fails to perform the `HeadObject` operation with a 400 response code.  The issue is that the credentials boto3 is using seem to be invalid because when I manually assume the "Task Role" and provide those credential values to the container via environment variables, everything works perfectly.

The environment variable `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` is being defined automatically, I am not setting it myself, and appears valid.  I have confirmed the task has access to the public internet as well as private connectivity within the VPC as it's able to access an RDS instance, which is on a private subnet in the same VPC.

I have used the reachability analyzer to confirm there are no issues and - again - I have another account with the same CloudFormation templates where this runs perfectly.  So, I am thinking this is some kind of bug in boto3 itself.

Any help is greatly appreciated, even if it's just suggestions of how to debug.  I've done everything I can think of at this point.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but one possible cause I came up with is that, in each container of an ECS task, because special AWS envrionment variables including `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` are only set to a process with pid=1, if your application runs multiple processes within a single container, then you may have to configure these special AWS envrionment variables are properly pass down from pid=1 to other processes (such as a process running AWS SDK code).

Comment: The DNS configuration you describe (what you call cross-account domain forwarding) is only relevant for the initial DNS resolution for inbound network connections to your application. It is not used AT ALL for outbound connections, and is not in any way relevant to the error you are encountering.

Comment: Are you actually setting the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` value yourself? That is an environment variable that ECS sets automatically if you have an ECS Task Role defined. You shouldn't even need to look at or mess with that environment variable at all. If you simply use the Boto3 default credential provider, it will pick that up and use it automatically.  You should literally just be doing things like this in your Boto3 code: `boto3.client('s3')` without any credentials or anything configured at all, and it will then pick up the ECS task role.

Comment: @Shigerello The variable is already defined.

Comment: @MarkB Interesting feedback on the outbound side.  I am not setting this value myself.

Comment: @GoForth, can you confirm that `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` is actually set in your Python process, for example, by looking into `os.environ` . Also, can you edit the question to include JSON of the ECS task definition, which can be obtained from `aws ecs describe-task-definition` or AWS managed console of ECS tasks; it will help others to understand how your Python application is structured and configured, and give some insight into what is wrong.

Comment: @Shigerello Yes, the value is set as "/v2/credentials/f11cb8c1-606f-4e1d-8f1a-20f62ad276bb".  I have also confirmed with Reachability analyzer that this is not a network issue.  For some reason boto3 is getting invalid credentials and I still don't know why.

Comment: @MarkB I updated the question now that I determined this is definitely a credential issue.  When providing my own credentials everything just works.  Would you say this is definitely a boto3 bug?  Should I open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: @GoForth With the updated status, now boto3 is suspicious. Can you confirm the following? (1) In your Python code, you have a control over initialization of boto3's session and S3 client that no explicit credentials are set. If not, there is a possibility unintended credentials (e.g. profile name or API key) are implicitly set somewhere. (2) Similar to (1), in your Python process, there are no special AWS environment variables like `AWS_PROFILE` or `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are set. (3) Python module `boto3` is intact; no code is altered, or mocked for a testing purpose.

Comment: I've got several ECS/Fargate containers running Python code with Boto3 that work just fine, and I'm sure thousands of other people do as well. So I find it doubtful that this is a bug in Boto3.

Comment: @MarkB Yeah, like I said before I also have no issues with boto3 except in this account it's clear the credentials are invalid.  Even when I manually fetch the credentials they are invalid.  So, it seems like boto3 is behaving properly even though the creds are invalid.